# VB.net Adding Picturebox with Label and Scrollbar dynamically

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, label, scrollbar, picturebox

So basically what I wish to accomplish is that I set total of Pictureboxes to add and each picturebox has its own according label and if we reach 6 images we allow the scrollbar to go down.

**Example:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgWjP.png

As you can see pictures are added accordingly with label.
How can I do this in code?

Currently I got something like this:

```
' Total PictureBoxes/Labels to Generate
Dim wTotalPictures = 1

' Original PictureBox Starting Point
Dim wOriginalLocation = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 54)

' Assigned Label Title
Dim wImageTitle As String = "PictureTitle"

Dim wNewImage As New PictureBox
Dim wImageSize = New Size(122, 173)

With wNewImage
    .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    .Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jason\Pictures\newImage.jpg")
    .Location = wOriginalLocation
    .Size = wImageSize
End With
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I've now managed to change it into this, this works way better but still not 100% automatic like I want it.

```
' Total PictureBoxes/Labels to Generate
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim wTotalPictures = 5

    ' Original PictureBox Starting Point
    Dim wOriginalLocation = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 54)

    ' Assigned Label Title
    Dim wImageTitle As String = "PictureTitle"
    Dim wImageSize = New Size(122, 173)

    Dim wNewLocation As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = wTotalPictures

        ' Setup
        Dim wNewImage(i) As PictureBox
        wNewImage(i) = New PictureBox

        ' Execute
        wNewImage(i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        wNewImage(i).Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jason\Pictures\newImage.jpg")
        wNewImage(i).Size = wImageSize

        If wNewLocation < 480 Then
            wNewImage(i).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40 + wNewLocation, 54)
        ElseIf wNewLocation = 480 Then
            wNewImage(i).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 258)
            wNewLocation = 0
        End If

        ' Add to Form
        MyTab.Controls.Add(wNewImage(i))
        wNewImage(i).BringToFront()

        wNewLocation = wNewLocation + 160
        i += 1
    Loop
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: If you already know there will be 6 why not add them in the designer?

Comment: Because there will be more than 6, hence "dynamically".
If I set 14 I want there to be 14, etc.

Comment: Don't think your image link is working properly.  Have you looked at using a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the PictureBoxes will be **arranged automatically** for you?

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the image.
Also, I'll prefer without using flowlayoutpanel